# Can't find gcc-11 11.3.0 for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to downgrade my version of gcc-11 from 11.4 to 11.3, but when I check the [packages repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gcc-11), I only see 11.2 and 11.4. Is there a way to safely install version 11.3 for Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 never *had* 11.3.  11.3 only was present in Lunar 23.04.  You are not going to be able to *easily* or *safely* install 11.3 in 22.04 because it was never present in 22.04